# Azure terraform import error, unable to import resource

Tags: azure, terraform

[image: Module Structure]

This is my module structure

[image: I am calling a module of resource group]

However, when I am trying to import this resource I am getting below error, what could be the reason?

Module:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.resource_group_location
  tags     = var.tags
}
```

Resource:

```
  module "importtestrs" {
  source                  = "../modules/resource_group"
  resource_group_name     = var.resource_group_name
  resource_group_location = var.location
  tags                    = var.tags
}
```

Terraform init and plan worked fine!

2022-03-01T09:43:35.4574585Z ##[command]"terraform" import -var-file="variables-dev.tfvars" module.importtestrs.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/DevOps-Agent-Dev -input=false -no-color
2022-03-01T09:43:35.5479792Z The import command expects two arguments.
2022-03-01T09:43:35.5481231Z Usage: terraform [global options] import [options] ADDR ID

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, but properly formated code blocks.

Comment: All the options you want to provide, like `-input` should probably go before the module import name and ID.

Comment: @marcin apologies, I post the screenshots for showing the folder structure. I have added the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply by

```
terraform import resource_group.resourcename id
```

in your case it will be

```
terraform import azurerm_resource_group. resource_group /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/DevOps-Agent-Dev
```